# Updating two tables in a many-to-one relationship through a view in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables: `foos` and `bars`, and there is a many-to-one relationship between them: each `foo` can have many `bars`. I also have a view `foobars`, which joins these two tables (its query is like `select foo.*, bar.id from foos, bars where bar.foo_id=foo.id`).

EDIT: You would not be wrong if you said that there's a many-to-many relationship between `foo`s and `bar`s. A `bar`, however, is just a tag (in fact, it is a size), and consists just of its name. The table `bars` has the same role as a link table would have.

I have a rule on inserting to `foobars` such that the “foo” part is inserted to `foos` as a new row, and “bar” part, which consists of a couple of bar-id's separated by commas is split, and for each such part a link between it and the appropriate `foo` is created (I use a procedure to do that).

This works great for inserts. I have a problem, however, when it comes to updating the whole thing. The `foo` part of the rule is easy. However, I don't know how to deal with the multiple `bar`s part. When I try to do something like `DELETE FROM bars WHERE foo_id=new.foo_id` in the rule, I end deleting everything from the table `bars`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way of achieving what I need? Finally, is my approach to the whole thing sensible?

(I do this overcomplicated thing with the view because the data I get is in the form of “`foo` and all its `bar`s”, but the user must see just `foobars`.)

Answer (score 2):

Rysiek, if I understood correctly, you have text column in `foos` table that is parsed to extract foreign keys pointing to `bars` table. This approach to building relations may be justified in some cases, however almost every guide/tutorial to database programming would discourage doing so. Why not use standard foreign key in `bars` that would point to foo in `foos`? Unless there is a requirement for bars to be assigned to more than one foo. If so, this identifies your relation as many-to-many rather one-to-many. In either situation using standard foreign key based solution seems much more natural for database.

Example db schema for one-to-many relation:

```
CREATE TABLE foos (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
);
CREATE TABLE bars (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    foo_id INT REFERENCES bars (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ...
);
```

And the same for many-to-many relation:

```
CREATE TABLE foos (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
);
CREATE TABLE bars (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
CREATE TABLE foostobars (
    foo_id INT REFERENCES foos (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    bar_id INT REFERENCES bars (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I would also recommend using INNER JOIN instead of table multiplication (SELECT FROM foos, bars).

```
CREATE VIEW foobars AS
SELECT
    foos.id AS foo_id, foos.something,
    bars.id AS bar_id, bars.somethingelse
FROM foos
INNER JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = foo.id;
```

The same for many-to-many INNER JOINS

```
CREATE VIEW foobars AS
SELECT
    foos.id AS foo_id, foos.something,
    bars.id AS bar_id, bars.somethingelse
FROM foos
INNER JOIN foostobars AS ftb ON ftb.foo_id = foo.id
INNER JOIN bars ON bars.id = ftb.bar_id;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the explicit and implicit inner join be optimized exactly to the same query plan? That's what happens in Postgres, at least. I edited the post to explain why I don't use a link table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think new.foo_id is correct in the context of a delete.

Shouldn't it be DELETE FROM bars WHERE foo_id=old.foo_id?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have actually dealt with it: when I get a unique constraint violation, instead of updating I simply delete the `foo` and let the cascade take care of the `bars`. Then I simply try to insert once again. I have to use more than one SQL statement to do it, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The deletion problem is that you are deleting on a predicate that is not based on the table you are deleting from.  You need to delete based on a join predicate.  This would look something line:

```
delete b
  from foo f
  join foobar fb
    on f.FooID = fb.FooID
  join bar b
    on b.BarId = fb.BarID
 where f.FooID = 123
```

This lets you jave a table of Foo's, a table of Bar's and a join table that records what Bar's the Foo has.    You don't need to compose lists and split them apart.  This is a bad thing because the query optimiser can't use an index to identify the relevant records - in fact this violates the 1NF 'No repeating groups' rule..  The correct schema would look something like:

```
Create table Foo (
     FooID int
    ,[Other Foo attributes]
)

Create table Bar (
     BarID int
    ,[Other Bar attributes]
)

Create table FooBar (
     FooID int
    ,BarID int
)
```

With appropriate indexes, the M:M relationship can be stored in FooBar and the DBMS can store and manipulate this efficiently in its native data structures.